# Should I be concerned about the movement of control dials on a battery grip when the camera is moved in or out of a camera bag?

Tags: equipment-protection, camera-bag, battery-grip

I have a Pentax K-5 with battery grip D-BG4 attached.  Whenever I move the camera in or out of my camera bag (a Tamrac Pro 12), the front e-dial is audibly moved.  Should I be concerned about this possibly causing excessive wear and tear to the e-dial assembly on the grip?  (I can't adjust the camera bag much farther.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your bag moves the dial more often then you do, then give the camera to someone who uses it more :)

Seriously, while there will be measurably more use, it should be comparatively marginal. Perhaps it will die a day sooner than otherwise but I wouldn't be concerned about this.

Comment: I'm with Itai. Besides, both my K-5s have a grip on them and I abuse them terribly, so I think it's probably safe.